# Grandtotal on Gridview with pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am trying to show a grad total of hours worked from a gridview that has multiple pages.

this is what i'm doing now:

```
 protected void gwWorkhours_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int hour = 0;
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            string hours = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "hours").ToString();
                Int32.TryParse(hours, out hour);
                completeCount += hour;
        }

    }
```

but it only shows me the total for the first page.

i am using ObjectDataSource to populate the grid like so:

```
 gwWorkhours.DataSourceID = "ObjectDataSource1";
        gwWorkhours.DataBind();
```

is it possible to maybe get the datatable from the objectdatasource after it has been bound to the gridview, to then iterate through it? i don't want to have to make another call to the database unless i really have to.

Comment: Let me ask this, does it make sense to have the grand total be a part of the `GridView` at all? For instance, say I have a column that represents the number of books in a collection and the first page of the grid shows 10 records. Each of the rows has a count of 2, so the total for the page is 20, but there are 20 pages to the grid in total, so the grand total for all the data is 400. As a user I would be confused to see 10 rows with a value of 2 and then a total of 400 in the footer below the 10th row. I would think the logic of the program was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, as you've already realized, you're only getting a total for one page because you're only adding up that one page. You can get the actual `ObjectDataSourceView` like this:

```
var view = this.dataSource.GetView() as ObjectDataSourceView;
```

and then you can issue a `Select` like this:

```
view.Select(null);
```

The parameter is of type `DataSourceSelectArguments`, so if you need to pass in arguments, you'll need to build one of those.

- [`Select` Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16by81fh.aspx)
- [`GetView` Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.getview.aspx)